# Updating the value of a subItem in a ListViewItem inside a listview c# (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I would like to update the data contained in a ListviewItem contained itself in a ListView.
The idea is when a row of the listview is selected, I click on a button and the data is updated .

I have this code :

```
ListView listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();   
ListViewItem lv1 = new ListViewItem("me");    
lv1.SubItems.Add("my brother");    
listView1.Items.Add(lv1);

Button myB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();

private void myB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.SelectedItems[0]  ....... ;
}
```

I know how to go any further to acces to modify the value of "my brother" to "my sister".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if something is selected then access the first ListViewItem in the SelectedItems

```
if(listView1.SelectedItems != null)
{
   ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
   item.SubItems[0].Text = "Sister";
}
```

this is the [reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.aspx) for ListViewSubItem class

Comment: You're my hero.Thanks for the quick answer.