# Change ListView Item Value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

This is the first time that I have used ListView so please go easy on me XD. 
For some reason if I try to use `.Value` or `.Text` to replace the listview item column value I get the error `Public member` ... `on type 'String' not found.`

Not sure what this means or why I can't replace the value.

Any suggestions?

I referenced the link on how to do this here

[Updating the value of a subItem in a ListViewItem inside a listview c# (Winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182463/updating-the-value-of-a-subitem-in-a-listviewitem-inside-a-listview-c-sharp-win)

```
 For x = 1 To ArrMapsCt
            With ArrMaps(x)
                If UCase(.CallCenterID) = UCase(cfg.CallCenter) Then 'mdlConfig
                    y = y + 1

                    If frmMain.cboMap.Items.Count >= .MapID Then

                       'Dim li As ListViewItem
                       'li = frmMain.lstStations.Items(.MapID)
                       'li.SubItems(0).Text = ArrMaps(x).MapName


                        'frmMain.cboMap.Items(.MapID).Text = ArrMaps(x).MapName 
                        'frmMain.cboMap.Items(.MapID).Value =  ArrMaps(x).MapName) 'ERROR LINE
                    Else
                        frmMain.cboMap.Items.Add(ArrMaps(x).MapName)
                    End If

                End If


        Next
```

Comment: What is the exact line that gives that error?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: the error line that says `ERROR LINE`. And I don't understand why I get this error line when it looks like I should be able to use `.Value`

Comment: Because those aren't items.  What is `cboMap`?

Comment: ...that moment you thought you were working on a list but it was a combo box instead

Comment: Next time, read the error message & look at the thing that it claims is different from what you expect.